# Infinite IntentService stops working when there is no breakpoint

Tags: android, intentservice

I have got an infinite IntentService meant to enable scanner for all the time application is alive. And whenever there is a breakpoint - it works fine. But when I remove a breakpoint from a loop - it stops working after some time. And then again when I put a breakpoint - it starts working again. What the heck? How can I fix this?

```
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent)
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if (!blocked)
                {
                    blocked = true;
                    String received = GlobalAccess.scan.scan(1000);

                    if (received != null && !received.isEmpty())
                    {
                        //TODO: some stuff here
                    }
                    blocked = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

**EDIT**
I have created my `CustomService` with

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if (!blocked)
                {
                    blocked = true;
                    String received = GlobalAccess.scan.scan(1000);

                    if (!Objects.equals(received, null) && !received.isEmpty())
                    {
                        //TODO: some stuff here
                    }
                    blocked = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(runnable, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

But it has exact same bahavior as `IntentService`

Comment: "infinite IntentService" -- don't do that. Create your own `Service` with your own thread pool (or, in this case, perhaps a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of a thread pool).

Comment: I have tried creating my own `Service` but it blocked my UI

Comment: That is because you did not set up your own thread pool, `ScheduledExecutorService`, or something else to move the business logic to a background thread. `IntentService` is designed for short transactional bits of work.

Comment: I wonder what's the reasoning behind usage of `Handler`?

Comment: Can you provide any tutorial for creating my own thread pool in service?

Comment: I'm so frustrated so I'm trying all I can find @azizbekian

Comment: @CommonsWare updated answer

Comment: Get rid of your `Thread.sleep()`, `blocked`, `while(true)`, etc. Then use one of the other methods on `ScheduledExecutorService`, such as `scheduleWithFixedDelay()`. Your `Runnable` would just have the business logic (`GlobalAccess` and `Objects`).

Comment: And that, Sir, Is a great answer! thank you very much!

Comment: Can I safely start new activities from this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CommonsWare I have managed to solve my problem.
This is the solution:

```
public class ScanService extends Service
{
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                String received = GlobalAccess.scan.scan(1000);

                if (!Objects.equals(received, null) && !received.isEmpty())
                {
                    //TODO: some stuff here
                }
            }
        };
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```